# Are inventory unlocks specific for each character?

Tags: guild-wars-2

The bag slots that can be unlocked (for 400 gems each, currently) are just for the character that purchases them or you only have to unlock them once for the account?

Also related, I assume that unlocking storage in the bank is at an account level, but I'd also like to confirm this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bag Slot Expansions](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Bag_Slot_Expansion) apply [to the character](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/index.php?title=Talk:Bag_Slot_Expansion&oldid=326362), and [Bank Tab Expansions](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Bank_Tab_Expansion) apply to the account.